# pandas dataframe reshape after pivot

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, pivot-table

The pivot code:

```
result = pandas.pivot_table(result, values=['value'], index=['index'], columns=['columns'], fill_value=0)
```

The result:

```
        value   value   value   
columns col1    col2    col3    
index
idx1    14      1       1
idx2    2       0       1
idx3    6       0       0
```

I tried:

```
result.columns = result.columns.get_level_values(1)
```

Then I got this:

```
columns col1    col2    col3
index
idx1    14      1       1
idx2    2       0       1
idx3    6       0       0
```

Actually what I would like is this one:

```
index   col1    col2    col3
idx1    14      1       1
idx2    2       0       1
idx3    6       0       0
```

Is there anyway to achieve this? Help really is appreciated. Thank you in advance.

Comment: Sorry are you moaning about the `index` name? you can do `df.index.name = None` to remove it

Comment: actually I want the 'index' to remain, but the 'columns' (the columns name) to goes away

Comment: you can do `df.columns.name = None`

Comment: yes, that's what I needed. Thanks EdChum. Please post below so I could resolve this one

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need remove `index name` by [`rename_axis`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/whatsnew.html#changes-to-rename) (new in `pandas` `0.18.0`):

```
df = df.rename_axis(None)
```

If need also remove `columns name`, use:

```
df = df.rename_axis(None, axis=1)
```

If use older version of pandas, use:

```
df.columns.name = None
df.index.name = None
```

Sample (if remove `[]` from `pivot_table`, you remove `Multiindex` from columns):

```
print (result)
   index columns  value
0      1    Toys      5
1      2    Toys      6
2      2    Cars      7
3      1    Toys      2
4      1    Cars      9

print (pd.pivot_table(result, index='index',columns='columns',values='value', fill_value=0)
         .rename_axis(None)
         .rename_axis(None, axis=1))

   Cars  Toys
1     9   3.5
2     7   6.0
```

If use `[]`, get:

```
result = pd.pivot_table(result, values=['value'], index=['index'], columns=['columns'], fill_value=0)
            .rename_axis(None)
            .rename_axis((None,None), axis=1)
print (result)        
  value     
   Cars Toys
1     9  3.5
2     7  6.0
```

Comment: If remove `[]` from `pivot_table`, output is without `Multiindex` in columns, so `result.columns = result.columns.get_level_values(1)` is not necessary. Please check edit.

Answer (score 1):

Consider this dataframe:

```
results = pd.DataFrame(
    [
        [14, 1, 1],
        [2, 0, 1],
        [6, 0, 0]
    ],
    pd.Index(['idx1', 'idx2', 'idx3'], name='index'),
    pd.MultiIndex.from_product([['value'], ['col1', 'col2', 'col3']], names=[None, 'columns'])
)

print results

        value          
columns  col1 col2 col3
index                  
idx1       14    1    1
idx2        2    0    1
idx3        6    0    0
```

Then all you need is:

```
print results.value.rename_axis(None, 1)  # <---- Solution

       col1  col2  col3
index                  
idx1     14     1     1
idx2      2     0     1
idx3      6     0     0
```